# How to take the id of a <tr> or <td>?

Tags: javascript, html

I create dynamic a table in javascript. A row looks like this

```
<td id="user[i]['id']">user[i]['name']</td>
```

So I need the value `user[i]['id']` which represents the id of `<td>` or `<input>`.

How could I get the id ?

Comment: `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: How do you need the id? In what code are you trying to utilize the id?

Comment: I need to get the id value not the element by id. For example if I have id="name" , i need to get "name" to use it like a value

Comment: Explain better, put your JavaScript and HTML here so we can look at your problem.

Comment: @James, it's `getElementById` (not `ID`)

Comment: var header = '<tr><th>User ID</th><th>In Role</th></tr>'; for(var i = 0;i < users.length;i++ ) header+= '<tr><td id="'+users[i]['id']+'">'+ users[i]['name']+'</td><td>'+ '<input  type="checkbox" id="'+users[i]['id']+'" checked/>'+'</td></tr>';

Comment: @James - I'm allowed one spark of inspiration a month, I peaked early

Comment: @Moni, please **edit** your question (using the link just under the "tags") to add information - please don't put it in the comments.  (And remember to [format your question](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so that code/HTML is displayed correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the attribute value with the following:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].id;
```

Comment: `.id` is a property of the element in the DOM... you don't need `.getAttribute("id")`